# Неправильно отрабатывает php при запуске через CRON

Tags: php, api, вконтакте, cron

1. Я создал php скрипт, который загружает данные по рекламе из
   Вконтакте.
2. В логике этого скрипта зашит редирект для авторизации через api.
   Суть скрипта в следующем:

> ```
> 2.1. Берём данные для авторизации по api vk и отправляем запрос, в ответ получаем code.
> 2.2. Делаем редирект на этот же скрипт, но с заданным параметром запроса code.
> ```

Данный скрипт прекрасно работает, если запускать его непосредственно через браузер.
Однако, при запуске через CRON данные не загружаются.
Возможно я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что проблема в том, что cron выполняет только первую часть (2.1) и когда дело доходит до редиректа, cron просто закрывает страницу, поэтому вторая часть скрипта не отрабатывает.
В CRON я пишу следующий код
    wget -O - -q -t 1 `http://ydomain.com/load_in_db/vk.php`
Ниже представляю код который используется для получения данных их api vk

```
    require_once "../db_login.php";
    require_once "../functions.php";
    require_once 'functions.php';

require_once('src/VK/VK.php');
require_once('src/VK/VKException.php');

$vk_config = array(
    'app_id'        => '1111111',
    'api_secret'    => '1111111',
    'callback_url'  => 'http://mydomain.com/load_in_db/vk.php',
    'api_settings'  => (65536+32768)
);
try {
    $vk = new VK\VK($vk_config['app_id'], $vk_config['api_secret']);

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        $authorize_url = $vk->getAuthorizeURL(
            $vk_config['api_settings'], $vk_config['callback_url']);
        header("Location: ".$authorize_url);
    } else {
        $access_token = $vk->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['code'], $vk_config['callback_url']);          
        $stats = $vk->api('ads.getStatistics', array(
            'account_id' => '11111111',
            'ids_type'    => 'office',
            'ids'     => '11111111',
            'period' => 'day',
            'date_from' => '0',
            'date_to' => '0',
            'v' => '5.100'
        ));
        $stats=$stats["response"][0]["stats"];
        set_costs_in_db($stats, 'Таргетинг ВК');

    }
} catch (VK\VKException $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы скрипт отрабатывал через cron. У меня закончились идеи)))

Comment: Задайтесь вопросами: 1) От имени какой учётной записи выполняется скрипт? 2) Какая часть профиля загружена? 3) Какой каталог - текущий?

Comment: 1) Насколько я понимаю от админа, т.к. cron задание задано в cpanel.

Comment: Кто такой "админ"? какая у него учетная запись?

Comment: Так, стоп. Боюсь дело не в учётных записях, т.к. это не первый скрипт, который запускается по cron и остальные скрипты отлично отрабатывают. Полагаю, что если бы проблемы были в учётной записи, то ниодин скрипт бы не запускался.

Comment: странно, что вы не запускали команду в терминале. запустите и убедитесь, что программа *cron* не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Да, похоже Вы правы. Проблема не в CRON, а в авторизации.

Comment: проблема в путях. и в том что вы не видите сообщения об ошибках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пути всегда должны быть абсолютными.**

Это правило для любых скриптов, но чаще всего проявляется именно при попытке выполнить скрипт через крон. Научиться отличать абсолютный путь от относительного можно [здесь](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths)

Плюс обязательно нужно видеть сообщения об ошибках. Для этого в начало кронтаба поместить строчку `mailto="email"`ю Тогда не придется гадать, в каком примерно месте скрипта остановилось выполнение, а сразу решать конкретную проблему.